# Set maximum width to the minimum of 90% and 300px

Tags: css

Is there a way to set *maximum width* of an element to the minimum of 90% or 300px using pure CSS?

*P.S.* Currently it's done using media queries and apriori information about the document layout, but I am looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `width` to be `90%` and `max-width` to be `300px`. In this case it will be `300px` if `90% > 300px` and `90%` if `90% < 300px` (considering the fact that your element is a block element where its width should be `100%` by default)

```css
.box {
  width:90%;
  max-width:300px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to achieve this is something like that:

```
@media (max-width: 300px) and (max-width: 90%) {
    .stuff {width: 300px}
}
```

So you won't get around using media queries.